# What is the equivalent of the "is" operator for reflected generic types?

Tags: c#, reflection

Using the `is` operator in C# with generic types is straightforward:

```cs
if (new List<MyClass>()) is IEnumerable<MyClass>) {
    // always branches
}
```

But what about when comparing types? I was hopeful that I could use `Type.IsSubclassOf(Type type)` here, but `System.Collections.Generic.List<>` *implements* `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<>` -- It doesn't *extend* it. So I assume that's why the following happens:

```cs
var listType = typeof(List<MyClass>);
var enumerableType = typeof(IEnumerable<MyClass>);

if (listType.IsSubclassOf(enumerableType)) {
    // NEVER branches
}
```

If I had an instance of my rvalue `Type` I could easily use `Type.IsInstanceOfType(object o)`, but this point in the code is far removed from the instance from which the `Type` in question was reflected.

Am I missing something in the `Type` API? Am I forced to roll my own via an extension method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Type.IsAssignableFrom(Type)

Comment: Complete sample is available on MSDN in [Type.IsSubclassOf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.issubclassof%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).